# Adding name to button of datatable column

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, datatable

I added a button to my datatable but I am unable to add it a name button:

```
  {"mDataProp": "myColumn","sClass":"center",
            fnRender: function (oObj) { 
            return '<input type="button" class="editRowClass" name="Edit"/>';
            }}
            ]
```

The button is correctly displayed and associated action is performed but name Edit is not displayed. How can I achieve my goal?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `value` not `name`